# Programmatically export/print to XPS - WordAPI

Tags: office365, office-js, word-addins

Is it possible to export/print to XPS programmatically in an OfficeJS addin? Looking at the docs I see only 3 [FileType enum members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.filetype?view=word-js-1.3). Is there a reason other (fixed) formats are not supported?

In the Word web app I don't have the option so this might be a reason. By default, I can only see the export to PDF option.

Are there any plans to add XPS or any other formats in the future versions of WordAPI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Compressed` output which is represented by the byte array and pass it to the web server where you can use any tools (for example, Open XML SDK) to save the document in the format you need. Following that way you will retrieve the file saved using XPS file format.

Comment: Being a fixed format I would like to be able to save the client version since in the past we had issues with different clients & (minor) office versions outputting different XPS files.

Comment: The XPS file format is not supported in Office web add-ins. I've suggest a possible workaround. You can also post your suggestion at http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thank you! I posted on the suggestions website as well: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-saving-as-xps-fixed-formats-from-wordapi/idi-p/2479444#M160